# Is Area what I am looking for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm new to MVC2 or MVC in general. I'm gone do basic app with a backend. Now I been thinking about how I should do with the folders, views, controllers & routes for the AdminFolder. Now I just saw something called **Areas**. Is that a way to go for me?

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - ASP.Net MVC 2 Areas is a nice way to organize your site into functional areas.

Suppose you have a site which needs the following sections:

- Admin - manages the web site
- Blog - a place to put in a blog
- Account - a place for registered users to manage their own account
  ...

You can then consider each of those sections as "areas" of your application & organize them accordingly...

HTH.

Comment: Is this how you would do, using areas? Or would you just keep the regular structure and do a separate folder for Admin only?

Comment: @Dejan - IMO areas are distinct blocks of functionality in the application. So, I would have separate areas for Admin, Blog, Account since they represent very distinct functionality of the application & I can have each area having its own Model/Views/Controllers & if I want to push it - its own UI master page